# Sources of information about flight times and delays

Tags: connecting-flights, delays, compensation, missed-flights

I booked travel from Perth Australia (QF648 2350 11 April 2019) via Melbourne Australia to Christchurch New Zealand (QF133 0715 12 April 2019) but there was a delay in Perth. Because I was going to miss my connection in Melbourne, Qantas transferred me to Air New Zealand in Melbourne so I could travel to Christchurch via Auckland on flights NZ722 and NZ555. I *think* there was also some sort of delay with one or other of those flights but I'm not sure, and I got to Christchurch too late on 12 April 2019 to travel to the town where I had pre-booked accommodation so I had extra expenses in Christchurch.

I’m now trying to complete a travel insurance claim but I can’t remember all the details. Is there a free open-source list of that kind of thing? It’s not like I have to prove in the claim that the delays occurred because I would guess the insurance company is going to check that in any case; but I would like to get the details right.

Comment: No, not a duplicate. One of the things about that question in your link was that it wasn't clear what, exactly, the OP was asking., evidenced by the opening remark "What do you want to know about these flights?" of the first answerer. I don't think that that is the case at all with my question. Additionally, I don't thik that my question needs to be edited to make it clear how it is different from the cross-referenced one. A careful reading of the other question makes it clear that the two are not the same.

Comment: @user02814 No, really, how is your question different? You want to know the arrival times of some flights in the recent-ish past, outside the USA. That's exactly what the other question is asking and the answers tell you exactly where to find it.

Comment: First, the previous question was asked 6 years ago; things change. Second, I have changed one word 'public' in my earlier posting to 'free, open-source' in the edited version. That should distinguish it from the previously cited question and answer. In that answer, the cited sources (Flight Aware and Flight Stats) both charge for historical data from more than a few days ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking specifically for a **free and open source** list of information, I regret to inform you that nothing of the kind exists: all data sources known to me are copyrighted and not free.

Source: I maintain OpenFlights.org, one of the internet's primary repositories of free flight data.

Comment: Thank you. That's nice and clear ... and different from the answer to the actually different question of which this is now marked as a duplicate. I'll rely on my memory for my insurance claim an just leave it to my insurance company to check the details .